# Proof for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\sin n}{n} = 0$

Tags: limits

**Problem**

Use the technique described in 4.3.1 (posted below) to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\sin n}{n} = 0$

**Definition 4.3.1**

> The series $\{a_n\}$ converges to a number $a$ if for any real number $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a number $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $|a_n-a| < \varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

Is this related to the epsilon/delta definition of a limit by any chance?

**My work so far**

Let $a_n = \frac{2\sin n}{n}$, then $|a_n-0| = |a_n| = |\frac{2\sin n}{n}|$.

From here I need to show that there exists that $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $|\frac{2\sin n}{n}|<\varepsilon \ \forall \ n\geq N$, but this is where I get stuck.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you bound $|\sin n|$?

Comment: Yeah, that would be bounded between 0 and 1 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly the $\varepsilon$-definition for sequences. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $N > \frac{2}{\varepsilon}$. Then for any $n > N$ we have $$\left| \frac{2\sin n}{n} - 0 \right| = \left| \frac{2\sin n}{n}\right| \leqslant \frac{2}{n} < \frac{2}{N} < \varepsilon$$ since $\left| \sin n \right| \leqslant 1$.